# Is it possible to replace a laptop's processor?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, gaming

I currently own a 2016 Dell Inspiron 15 5000 and don't have enough money to buy a Gaming PC. I average around 20 FPS in Fortnite and was wondering if it is possible to replace the processor. I am currently running the Intel i5 that comes with it but I want to replace it with the Ryzen 5 2400g with Vega 11 graphics. I am not very intelligent about computers but the shapes of the processors are the same. If I bought this processor and replaced my Intel i5, would it be able to run? If not, are there any processors that I could use instead to get better use of my laptop for gaming?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, you can't. Even with a processor that fits the socket, most laptop CPUs are BGA, and therefore you'd need a BGA reworking kit and to know how to use it.

Comment: If it is all about graphics why not to try external GPU? I think its much better choice than replacing cpu.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU of the Dell Inspirion 15 5000 is soldered to the mainboard; however, you can change the board to another (so, you basically change the whole board + cpu).

You can't change **only** the CPU.

**Edit:** Also, please note, you never ever can swap an Intel with an AMD processor, since their [Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_socket) won't fit.