# What's the best replacement for Intel 1.4/1m/400 478 mobility today?

Tags: laptop

I have this laptop that my friend trow into my trash. It's a HP Compaq nx6110. It's kinda interesting hardware, many modules you can change, and of course, a very outdated. But I think with a Lubuntu it can be still useful, so I am researching and evaluating possibilities of hardware upgrade to make as best as possible (and affordable), beyond the simple memory/HDD upgrade.

I am aware there is some hackers replacing old 32 bit CPU for 64 bit compliant that will fit in the same socket. I know a real case of MacMini with Core 2 Duo now running 64 bit Ubuntu. By the product documentation, is not possible, the best one is the Pentium M 770 2.13 (so maybe the newer 780 will fit either). But a lot of new processors were developed after the documentation release. I was looking for models that will fit in the 478 socket, however, is not that simple, though. I guess a Pentium 4 will burn my laptop! Maybe newer CPU won't communicate right with old chipset so won't work - theories I have in mind.

So my question is - is there some 64 bit CPU that will work in my notebook? If not, what's the best one and what can I expect of performance improvement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to replace a laptop's processor?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8950/is-it-possible-to-replace-a-laptops-processor)

Comment: Would you please read my question? I know the processor can be replaced, I wish to know the best option. The title is clear, different and unique.

Comment: I re-read it and understand better what you are asking, my apologies.  Unfortunately, I don't think you are going to have much luck with a processor that is "undocumented" as it may just not be compatible.  You're free to try though.

Comment: The question pointed as possible duplicated were downvote and closed as off-topic. I am not sure if I understood the purpose of this forum. But in my case, the HP Compaq got a good documentation, it is just about asking for the detail needed, if the question is "on-topic".